# How to load node-blade templates client side. Error: request failed

Tags: node-blade

I've spent a few hours trying to track down a solution to this problem but it's been quite difficult.  I've read through the installation instructions and examples at https://github.com/bminer/node-blade#simple-example but can't seem to load client side blade templates.

Here is what I've done.

I have a client side template sitting in my public static server at /views/template.blade.

I've pulled in the blade "runtime.js" file and included it in a script tag at the bottom of the html body.

In my main.js file I'm trying to simply run the code:

```
blade.Runtime.loadTemplate("template.blade", function(err, tmpl){
    console.dir(err, tmpl);
});
```

I've verified that it's correctly accessing the template.blade file because it's sitting in the page source viewable from Chrome Dev Tools.  Also, if I change the above argument to "templateXYX.blade" I get a 404 error.

Yet I cannot get around the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token default template.blade:1
```

I've also received the following error during different permutations of testing:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http://localhost:3005/views/template.blade".
```

From the node-blade instructions I cannot understand if I am missing any setup.

Any idea why blade.Runtime.loadTemplate throws this error when reading in the template.blade file?  It's like it's trying to read the .blade file as a javascript file and failing to parse it?

Thanks for any clues.

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is correct; `blade.Runtime.loadTemplate` is trying to parse the *compiled* Blade template, but what it's getting is the Blade source file instead.

I believe that the key piece that you are missing is that you must load the *.blade file through the Blade middleware, not from the static file server middleware.  The Blade middleware is responsible for compiling the Blade template into JavaScript, caching the result in memory, and serving the compiled version to the client.

Checkout this link for [more information about the Blade middleware](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade#blademiddlewaresourcepath-options)

Please post back if you still have any questions or problems.  Thanks!